# How add localy hosted service (exe file) to debugger via attach process

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, debugging

I host locally webservice (*) and I run my Console Application which is working on data comes from this web service locally also.

When I try to debug my Consol App unfortunately debugger doesn't enter into my code. I tried to attach process to my debugger but unfortunately I have no process like w3wp or something like that.
I have one process which name is the same like my local web service (*).
The problem is I cannot attach it because I get an error:

```
"Unable to attach to the process. A debugger is already attached."
```

My question is: How to attach my local service to debugger?
My webservice is built to exe file but i don't know how to add it ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution:

1)Build project contains service. 
2)Check where required service is built to (RB on required service project -> Properties -> Build tab -> Output path).
3)Go to Output path and find out you service_name.exe
4)Run service_name.exe via double-click on icon.
5)Go back to your solutin (where service is located) and click: Debug -> Attach to process ..
6)Find out your service_name.exe and attach to solution. 
7)Put break point in your code and wait :) Should work :)